# Connecting UISwipeGuesture in Storyboard to Table View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoa-touch

Is it necessary to write an entire function to get a swipe gesture to select an index row? Typically for a table view you would use `indexPathForSelectedRow`. But if you don't want to have it be necessary for a user to actually press the cell and then swipe to get the correct index object to load in the detail view is there a class available for that, a connection in Storyboard, or do you need to write your own?

Currently the correct objects load when a row is selected and then swiped but if I just swipe I get the default value I set instead of the what would appear for `indexPathForSelectedRow`.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var upcoming: AnswerTable = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerTable

    if (segue.identifier == "loadAnswerTableView") {

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()

        println(indexPath)

        let obj: PFObject? = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    upcoming.parseObject = obj

    self.tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!, animated: true)

    }
```

This `prepareForSegue` function is triggered by a UISwipeGesture that is implemented in Interface Builder(Storyboard). Because the function gets the data to pass to the detail view from  `let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()` the cell must be physically selected by the user touching the table cell and selecting it. Instead of the user having to do this I want the UI to recognize that I want the data from the cell that was swiped over to be passed to the detail view controller.

I'm sure this can be done programmatically, though I don't know the correct implementation yet. But before going in and doing it programmatically I am wondering if there is a way to assign the swipe gesture to the `prepareForSegue` method through Storyboard or if there is a class in the UIKit that can handle this.

Comment: What's the exact question you're asking? It's a bit vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of the above answers do work. This is the third solution I was able to come up with.

After playing around with it I was able to compress the lines written with the rather handy `indexPathForRowAtPoint`. It seems this method was written specifically for this type of handling. By substituting `indexPathForSelectedRow` with `indexPathForRowAtPoint` you can pass it the `CGFloat` it needs by writing a simple three line function:

```
@IBOutlet var swipeGesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer!


func locationInView(touches: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> CGPoint {

    var swipeTouch = touches.locationInView(self.view)

    return swipeTouch

}
```

The final code looks like this:

```
func locationInView(touches: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) -> CGPoint {

    var swipeTouch = touches.locationInView(self.view)

    return swipeTouch

}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    var upcoming: AnswerTable = segue.destinationViewController as! AnswerTable

    if (segue.identifier == "loadAnswerTableView") {

        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(locationInView(swipeGesture))

        println(indexPath)

        let obj: PFObject? = self.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    upcoming.parseObject = obj

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a suggestion of how I would implement this. 
Instead of attaching the gesture to the TableView, I would attach it to the the    UITableViewCell, and in cellForRowAtIndexPath function set the tag of UITableViewCell to that row number. and in the delegate/handler of the swipe gesture check which row initiated the swipe and do the appropriate action. Something like this. Its Objective C, but let me know if you want a SWIFT based answer, the concept is same.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     //Create the UITableViewCell //
     cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.row;
     UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] 
     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
     [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
     [cell.contentView addGestureRecognizer:swipeGesture];
}
```

And in your handler function

```
-(void)handleSwipe:(id)sender
{
   UIView *senderView = (UIView *)sender;
   //indexSwiped will have the row which was swiped and you
   //can process what to do in the detail view accordingly
   NSInteger indexSwiped = senderView.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using storyboard and you added the swipe gesture to a prototype cell, all you have to do is add the `tag` to the cell and pass that around like Qazi answered.

If you have different sections or you want to pass other things around you could create a custom cell and add those properties you want to pass around in there. In the case of having different sections, you could create a property holding the `indexPath` and pass it to the cell with `cell.indexPath = indexPath` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Example for CustomCell:

```
class CustomCell {
    // Some labels

    let indexPath: NSIndexPath!
}
```

Example for passing to prepareForSegue:

```
@IBAction func handleSwipe(sender: AnyObject) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier("loadAnswerTableView", sender: sender)
}
```

And in your prepareForSegue:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "loadAnswerTableView" {
        let cell = sender!.view as? CustomCell
        let obj: PFObject? = self.objectAtIndexPath(cell.indexPath)
        upcoming.parseObject = obj
    }
}
```